# UCM dynamicview config spec : excluding all *.xml but include build.xml

Tags: cleartool, clearcase-ucm

I am using Clearcase UCM with a dynamic view. (On linux)

In my view there many files ending in .xml. Some of there are  "build.xml"  files, others are data 
files.  I want to view only "build.xml" files in my view.

Following line in config spec  excludes all the "*.xml" files.

```
element *.xml -none
```

How can I include just the "build.xml" files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the select rule before the non-select rule

```
element build.xml .../yourStream/LATEST
element build.xml yourBaseline
element *.xml -none
```

Note: those rules should be put at the beginning of the UCM config spec of your view, otherwise the usual UCM select rules would be applied first, and you would end up seeing all files within your component.

Comment: @Jayan: beware of those rules manually added at the beginning of a UCM config spec: the next stream synchronization (`ct setcs -stream` from within your view) will re-generate the config spec and those rules will disappear.

Comment: Understood. We have a perl script to extract baselines and re-generate config spec for the view.